# Canot send SMS using gammu-smsd

Tags: ubuntu, sms, alert

I am trying to send SMS using gammu-smsd, but it does not work.

Modem: Huawei E1550

**Steps:**

```
#vi /etc/gammu-smsdrc

port= /dev/ttyUSB0
connection = at
```

Then restarted gammu-smsd:

```
# /etc/init.d/gammu-smsd restart
```

SMS Sending test

```
echo "Test message" | gammu-smsd-inject TEXT 335123456
```

It does not send SMS.

**Log**

```
Sep 27 14:19:25 Dell-Laptop gammu-smsd[10285]: Going to 30 seconds sleep because of too much connection errors
Sep 27 14:19:55 Dell-Laptop gammu-smsd[10285]: Starting phone communication...
Sep 27 14:19:55 Dell-Laptop gammu-smsd[10285]: Error at init connection: Error opening device, it doesn't exist. (DEVICENOTEXIST[4])
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure gammu itself is reading from a right device path, and your user profile is in dialout group.

You may need to adjust bitrate to communicate to the module, so try to initiate direct communication using as example `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` and see what value fits at best.

The tool `gammu-detect` is also available, for spotting an initial configuration with a device, so `man gammu-detect` for more info.